# Constant error when using the plot_time_series() function

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to plot a graph using the plot_time_series function and keep on getting the following error

```
> Retail %>%
+   plot_time_series(Date, Profit, .interactive = F)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `.value_smooth`.
x No method for class character.
i Input `.value_smooth` is `auto_smooth(...)`.
```

Any suggestions? I tried uninstalling the timetk package but that didn't work.

Comment: is your Profit column currently a character vector?

Comment: It was, such a noob mistake hahaha thanks!